# Find peaks in the data set for 2 different events

Tags: arrays, matlab, max

I have a data set that contains time and acceleration values. I want to identify regions of acceleration and deceleration, and then return the peak acceleration/deceleration values and associated time for each region. I have used 'findpeaks' function so far to find the peaks in the data but they contain both acceleration and deceleration peaks. Any help would be appreciated

```
[~,~,Data] = xlsread('data.xlsx');
 ts = cell2mat(Data(2:end,1))/1000; %% time in seconds
 av = cell2mat(Data(2:end,2)); %% acceleration values in m/s
 figure
 plot(ts,av)
 findpeaks(av,ts)
 [PKS,LOCS] = findpeaks(av,ts)
```

Comment: What does your dataset look like? Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: The data set consists of time  and acceleration/deceleration values

Answer (score 0):

If your data represents acceleration values, so the **findpeaks** function will return only the peak acceleration values. If you want also the peaks of deceleration, multiply your vector by -1 and call the function **findpeaks** again.

BTW if you only need regions of acceleration and deceleration, this would be any value which is not zero.

Example:
for the accelerated vector:

```
x = [1 2 5 7 7 8 3 1 2 2 2 -2 -4 -7 -3 -1 0 5];
```

it's plot would be:
[image]

and the `findpeaks` function will return the value 8 (which is the 6'th index).
When you will run the same function with the vector multiplied by -1, you will get the value -1 (which is the 8'th index). And again, a good visualization of that:
[image]

If your data contains negative values, you could use the pair: (MinPeakHeight, 0) in your findpeaks function as:

```
findpeaks(x, 'MinPeakHeight', 0);
```

for the acceleration problem, so you won't get negative acceleration. But, this depends on your specific problem details.

edit: as you can see, I added some negative values to the vector for a complete answer to your problem.
In the original graph, the acceleration peaks would be the indices: (6, 9) for positive, and (14) for negative.
The deceleration would be: (8).

So now, every acceleration will be any positive value which the findpeaks on the original vector returns; and every positive values the function returns on the flipped (multiplied by -1) vector.
As for the deceleration, it will be the exact opposite: negative values from the original vector and negative values from the flipped vector.

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: You are right. I am putting what I had done so far in the original post. The data does contain negative values too, so it is more or less a noisy data set. I understand what you said,  do you mean to say that            findpeaks(x, 'MinPeakHeight', 0); will give both acceleration and deceleration values?

Comment: No. When you add those values to the function, it means that you set a threshold. This means, that you will get peaks, only greater than the value you decided. But indeed, in your case it means that no negative acceleration will be included in your retrieved data (peaks). This is for the positive - acceleration. for the negative values - deceleration, it depends what you want. If you desire the negative values, you can do what I suggested (multiply by -1) and get only the positive peaks (again, use findpeaks with the extra variables of [MinPeakHeight, 0])

Comment: Yes I get your point. I used the parameter you suggested before posting the question here, but not sure sure on what basis do I choose the threshold value on

Comment: Well, again, it depends on your problem. What exactly is your goal? Let's think of what negative acceleration means - it's actually increasing the speed to the other direction. So, It's also some kind of acceleration but to the opposite direction.

Comment: The goal is to differentiate acceleration and deceleration data into different groups. Right now, it is a data accumulated for a bicycle so it has acceleration values when someone speeds up and deceleration when they hit the brakes, but just looking at data points you can't tell where the points are. Hence, I need to separate them somehow, i.e. find regions of acceleration and deceleration and then find the peaks within those values

Comment: -- Updated the answer to match your detailed explanations

Comment: Yes I tried what you said and it makes sense, I am trying to understand mathematically though. I guess what is the purpose behind flipping the input vector?

Comment: Oh it's just a trick to get minimum value, as the findpeaks function in matlab doesn't obtain the possibility of finding local minimum.
As for the intuition, as it makes sense that upper peaks are the accelerator points, the minimum point would be the deceleration points. and the minimum values are actually the same thing, but in the reversed direction

Comment: It is very confusing because when I use the negative vector, all it does is make acceleration value as deceleration and vice-versa which is making me confused as to how to find right index for these values

Comment: Further, how do I combine the respective acceleration and deceleration values from the two arrays? because the values and indices I obtain from findpeaks provides me indices on the peaks and not where that data may exist in the original array

Comment: It does return. Look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) of the function. If you get it's output with 2 params it will give you also the location:
    `[pks,locs] = findpeaks(data)`

Comment: Yes I have been able to find them. My question is do I combine the two data that I get from the positive array and the negative array?

Comment: No, because those are the accelerations and decelerations

Answer (score 0):

this is John BG [jgb2012@sky.com](http://jgb2012@sky.com)

1.- I recently came across a similar question in a different forum.

Let me use the same example signal as shown above in another answer:

```
x           = [1  2  5  7  7  8  3  1  2  2  2 -2 -4 -7 -3 -1  0  5]
```

2.- Replace the test signal with your xls data.

Try the following and let me know if it works:

```
x=[x x(end)]
dx=diff([0 x])
k=1
n=1

while k<numel(x)

    r(n).start=k
    r(n).slope=sign(dx(k))

    switch r(n).slope

        case 1
            while dx(k)>0             % up hill
                if k<numel(x)
                    k=k+1;
                end
                if k==numel(x)
                    break
                end
            end
            r(n).stop=k-1


        case -1
            while dx(k)<0              % down hill
                if k<numel(x)
                    k=k+1;
                end
                 if k==numel(x)
                    break
                end
            end
            r(n).stop=k-1


        otherwise                       %  flat
            while dx(k)==0
               if k<numel(x) 
                 k=k+1;
               end
               if k==numel(x)
                    break
                end
            end
            r(n).stop=k-1


    end

    n=n+1

end

n=n-1   % match n to amount of segments

for k=2:1:size(r,2)             % correction r(n>1).start
    r(k).start=r(k).start-1
end

for k=1:1:size(r,2)               % calculate segment slopes
    if x(r(k).stop)>x(r(k).start)
        r(k).slope=1
    end
    if x(r(k).stop)<x(r(k).start)
        r(k).slope=-1
    end
    if x(r(k).stop)==x(r(k).start)
        r(k).slope=0
    end
end

for k=1:1:size(r,2)                 % calculate peaks assuming max thrust sought regardless of sign
    L1=x([r(k).start:1:r(k).stop])
    k1=find(max(abs(L1)))
    if sign(L1(k1))>0
        r(k).peak=max(x([r(k).start:1:r(k).stop]))
    end
    if sign(L1(k1))<0
        r(k).peak=min(x([r(k).start:1:r(k).stop]))
    end
    if sign(L1(k1))==0
        r(k).peak=0
    end
end
```

2.-

test start stop of each segment

```
for k=1:1:size(r,2)               % test read each segment 
    x([r(k).start:1: r(k).stop])
end

ans =
     1     2     5     7
ans =
     7     7
ans =
     7     8
ans =
     8     3     1
ans =
     1     2
ans =
     2     2     2
ans =
     2    -2    -4    -7
ans =
    -7    -3    -1     0     5
```

3.-

test obtained slope values

+1: acceleration

-1: deceleration

0: constant velocity

```
r(:).slope
ans =
     1
ans =
     0
ans =
     1
ans =
    -1
ans =
     1
ans =
     0
ans =
    -1
ans =
     1
```

4.- testing peaks

```
r(:).peak

ans =
     7
ans =
     7
ans =
     8
ans =
     8
ans =
     2
ans =
     2
ans =
     2
ans =
    -7
```

if you find this answer useful would you please be so kind to consider marking my answer as Accepted Answer?

To any other reader, if you find this answer useful
please consider clicking on the arrow-up vote link

thanks in advance for time and attention

John BG

[jgb2012@sky.com](http://jgb2012@sky.com)

comment: as mentioned, I assumed that when a weak acceleration and hard deceleration within same segment, the peak is supposed to go to the harder thrust that it would be the higher deceleration.

If such is not the case you are after, if you really want the top positive thrust regardless that there may be a larger back-thrust in value for the peak then instead of:

```
for k=1:1:size(r,2)                 % calculate peaks assuming max thrust sought regardless of sign
    L1=x([r(k).start:1:r(k).stop])
    k1=find(max(abs(L1)))
    if sign(L1(k1))>0
        r(k).peak=max(x([r(k).start:1:r(k).stop]))
    end
    if sign(L1(k1))<0
        r(k).peak=min(x([r(k).start:1:r(k).stop]))
    end
    if sign(L1(k1))==0
        r(k).peak=0
    end
end
```

use

```
for k=1:1:size(r,2)                 
    L1=x([r(k).start:1:r(k).stop])
    k1=find(max(abs(L1)))
    if sign(L1(k1))>0 || sign(L1(k1))<0
        r(k).peak=max(x([r(k).start:1:r(k).stop]))
    end
    if sign(L1(k1))==0
        r(k).peak=0
    end
end
```

Comment: Generating random inputs to test above answer:instead  of the input signal                                                                                                           
x=[1  2 5 7 7 8 3 1 2  2 2 -2 -4 -7 -3 -1  0  5]       use the following:                                                                                      
L11=randi([-20 20],1,randi([5 10],1,1));
x=[];
for k=1:1:numel(L11)-1
    x=[x linspace(L11(k),L11(k+1),randi([5 10],1,1))]; 
end;x=floor(x);                        
stem(x);grid on